# What is the Rails 4 routing correct syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consulted by the ruby guides for the rails routing syntax http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html I am writing the rule.

```
get 'guess/(index)', :to "guess#index"
```

This syntax is giving me an error and only after the => sign is working correctly.

```
get 'guess/(index)', :to => "guess#index"
```

What is the right syntax ?

Answer (score 2):

### It's `to:`, not `:to`

That's not a Rails syntax issue, it's a Ruby syntax issue. You're missing either the "hash rocket" (`=>`) for the old `:key => value` hash syntax, or you need to move the colon and use `to:` for the new `key: value` syntax:

```
# Prior to Ruby 1.9:

get 'guess/(index)', :to => "guess#index"

#  or, in modern Ruby:

get 'guess/(index)', to: "guess#index"
```

Comment: The two syntaxes execute identically. If you truly are using Ruby 2.0.0, there is no difference between them.